# Re-enable right click on the Images where it is prevented

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, javascript, developer-tools

I swear that I don't have any bad Intentions, I just want to know the reason.

In the below you can see an alert that this website returns when I do a right-click on the Images :

[image]

I want to re-enable the right-click, so I opened *Inspect Element* (The same *Developer tool* in Firefox) and I searched for the alert words ("This photo is copyrighted") in the **.js** files :

[image]

When I change this lines and save them, the message in the alert changes to that sentences that I wrote instead of "This photo is copyrighted".

The question is, "Why when I remove whole the contents of this .js file, the alert remain active with the last sentence that I wrote there?"

I mean who I can re-enable the right-click?

Note that I don't want to download it, (I already can! Using *Page info --> Media* in Firefox, or the link of image in inspect element codes.) I just want to know how I can re-enable it!

And note that I don't want to *Disable Java Scripts*, because Java Script codes load the image.

Comment: Why done vote?!

Answer (score 1):

You can enable/disable JavaScript temporarily for that page through Chrome Dev Tools. For Chrome, the keyboard shortcut to open Dev Tools is F12, to reach the Settings panel is F1 & here you'll find the checkbox to Disable JavaScript in the General section. You can toggle the checkbox as needed to enable or disable JavaScript

[image]

Comment: As I said in the question, I don't want to disable JavaScript! because the image loads with java script. and if I disable the java script, I can't load the image in my browser. You can test it yourself. the site is **1x.com**. disabling Java Script after of loading the image can't help also!